# How to join editors to post DynamoDB (performance)

Tags: database, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Regarding this following schema (schema from amplify console / AppSync):

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  editors: [PostEditor] @connection(name: "PostEditors")
}

# Create a join model and disable queries as you don't need them
# and can query through Post.editors and User.posts
type PostEditor @model(queries: null) {
  id: ID!
  post: Post! @connection(name: "PostEditors")
  editor: User! @connection(name: "UserEditors")
}

type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  posts: [PostEditor] @connection(name: "UserEditors")
}
```

Let's assume we have:
1 post and 5000 users

Performances are better if I have 1 item in the table PostEditor with:
1 array of 5000 objects with properties users id and post id

or performances are better if I have have 5000 items with:
post id
user id

What I want to achieve is to be able to query PostEditor table to get:
Every post for a user
Every user for a post

Answer (score 0):

1 array of 5000 objects sounds problematic. What database are you using?

If you are using there are [certain limit of DDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html) that you should keep in mind. There is also some [query optimization guide of DDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html).

But end of the day you may need to do some benchmark to find the best way for your service.